# How can I refresh checkbox to reflect changes on UI?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to uncheck checkbox on unchecking another checkbox. The value is changed to "false" but it's not reflected on the UI.

// on checkbox click if neither "onlinebook","walkinbook" is checked
// I want to uncheck the checkboxes with the class "selector"

////////////////////////////this is the html code

```
                <div class="form-check custom-control-inline mb-2 mt-2">
                    <label class="form-check-label">

                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Online, new { name = "remember", @class = "form-input-styled checkbooking", @id = "onlinebook" })
                        @this.GCUResources("Online")`enter code here`
                    </label>

                </div>
                <div class="form-check custom-control-inline  mb-2">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.WalkIn, new { name = "remember", @class = "form-input-styled checkbooking", @id = "walkinbook" })
                        @this.GCUResources("WalkIn")
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 readonlyradio Groupbooktwo">

                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-blue-300 custom-control-inline ">@this.GCUResources("bookinglevel")</h6>
                <div class="form-check  custom-control-inline mb-2">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsClass, new { name = "remember", @class = "form-input-styled selector" })
                        @this.GCUResources("Class")
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check  custom-control-inline mb-2">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsMakeModelYear, new { name = "remember", @class = "form-input-styled selector" })
                        @this.GCUResources("IsMakeModelYear")
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check custom-control-inline  mb-2">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsVehicel, new { name = "remember", @class = "form-input-styled selector" })
                        @this.GCUResources("Vehicle")
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span id="GroupbookingtwoError"
                      class="validation-error-label field-validation-error"
                      data-valmsg-replace="true">
                    <span id="GroupbookingtwoError" class="">@this.GCUResources("Pleaseselectatleastone")</span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

////////////////and this is the JavaScript code

```
$(".checkbooking").click(function () {

    var chk1 = document.getElementById("walkinbook").checked;
    var chk2 = document.getElementById("onlinebook").checked;
    if (chk1 == true || chk2 == true) {
        $parent = $('.readonlyradio');
        $parent.find('input').removeAttr('disabled', '');
    }
    else {
        $parent = $('.readonlyradio');
        $parent.find('input').attr('disabled', '');
        $parent.find('span.checked').attr("IsClass", "");
        $( ".selector" ).prop( "checked", false );
        $(".selector").trigger("changed");
        $("#booking").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

i know it's long but simple

Comment: $parent.find('input').removeAttr('disabled', '') is not right removeAttr accepts one value ... have you checked whether you have js error on not?

Comment: $parent.find('input').attr('disabled', '');
it's working perfectly and no, i have no JS error
what i couldn't solve that the UI not responding to unchecking .selector

Comment: since you are using class could you please try removeAttr('checked'). i mean use $('.selector').removeAttr("checked");

Comment: Grammar and typos